# Free ($0) products in expresso-store reports

Tags: add-on, expresso-store, ecommerce

We have a (rare) situation where there are free items being 'sold' alongside paid items in an expresso-store. But we've noticed that these items don't appear in the **Reports** > **Orders** Report area of the module.

Any idea if this is possible, or suggestions on where to look to allow this?

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a bug, there are no settings which would affect the display of free items.

Can you please email support@exp-resso.com and we will follow up for you.